# Cannot read property `contentHeight` of Undefined in Ionic 2

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to get the scrollTop position in my Ionic 2 page, but it is just not working using simple jQuery.

Checkout my working example below, scroll the page and click on it, it will give you the `y` position number.

```js
$("body").click(function(){
    var scrollPost = $(document).scrollTop();
    alert(scrollPost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
<div class="test">Thats a test</div>
```

But jQuery method to get scrollTop does not work, it always return 0.

So I have planned to get it using the ionic way, [documentation here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#contentTop)

I am trying to use **dimensions.contentHeight**, **dimensions.contentTop**, but getting error. Below is my code.

**`home.html`** code:

```
<ion-content content>
    <div #topScroll>
  The world is your oyster.
  test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
  test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>test<br/><br/><br/><br/>kjh<br/>kjgh<br/>uitz<br/><br/><br/><br/>uztjhg<br/>kjh<br/>
  <div class="test">Thats a test</div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

### Edit 1

`home.ts` code updated

**`home.ts`** code:

```
    import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { AfterViewInit,Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })

    export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit  {

      @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, public navCtrl: NavController) {       
    }

ngAfterViewInit() {

    // Renderer2 used not Renderer, inject it before using
    this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (e) => {
      // Get contentHeight here
      var iscroll =  this.content.contentHeight;
// error - Property 'dimensions' does not exist on type 'Content'
      var iscroll2 = this. content.dimensions.contentHeight;
      alert(iscroll);
      alert(iscroll2);
    });
    }
```

> Error coming - cannot read property `contentHeight` of Undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For which line? `iscroll` or `iscroll2`?

Comment: You are trying to get hieght of undefined element, which means the elements doesnt exist. try `$(document).ready(function() {  //GET HEIGHT HARE  } );`
By the way shouldnt `<div #topScroll>` be `<div id="#topScroll">`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues here:

- You're using a jQuery click handler
- You're using `content` and not `#content` in the template

I'd do:

```
<ion-content #content><!-- omitted content --></ion-content>

// Make sure to import AfterViewInit and implement it
ngAfterViewInit() {

  // Renderer2 used not Renderer, inject it before using
  this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (e) => {
    // Get contentHeight here
  });
}
```

Comment: implemented as you guided, error coming - `Property 'dimensions' does not exist on type 'Content'` , updating my code

Comment: updated my `home.ts` code aswell, please have a look and guide further

Comment: now what exactly is happening is - on ionic serve, `alert` gives a value and then error - `Cannot read property 'contentHeight' of undefined` , if i scroll the page it says alert says `[object object]`

Comment: @user2828442 Have you checked where in `this.content` the `contentHeight` property actually is? Because you're using two ways right now, it's a bit strange.

Comment: doing ionic serve once again my be cache issue , let you know in a minute

Comment: see the error was related to cache issue, but  `contentHeight` is always returning `0` , `contentTop` is giving me the size of the screen which is `662` , how do i get the `y` value from top as i keep scrolling. I still stand with the  same problem.

Comment: i think `dimensions.contentTop` is the property which i need but how to use it >

Comment: now i tried `scrollHeight`, this is giving me `1649` , which is the total height, i need to know rhe height where i clicked, please help

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do tbh. Do you need the`y` coordinate relative to the `window` height when you click?

Comment: I need the top position, or you can say tge y position where i clicked not relative to my screen size which is 662 px but relative to scroll page size which is 1649...like if i click after Scrolling to the bottom of page result should be around 1649 and not 662

Comment: Maybe `1649 - y`?

Comment: I just need the y value of the clicked area , hope this makes things clear